# How can to list table split string value with substring_index in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

### projects

| id | name | task |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | pro_1 | 2:3 |
| 2 | pro_2 | 1:2 |
| 3 | pro_3 | 2:3:4 |

### tasks

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | task_1 |
| 2 | task_2 |
| 3 | task_3 |
| 4 | task_4 |

I list one task however projects table that id number is 3 have 3 tasks (2:3:4) values. How can I do this?

```
SELECT id as proID, name,(SELECT name from tasks where id =  substring_index(projects.tak,":",-1) ) as taskName 
from projects where id = 3
```

### Result List that I want

| proID | name | taskName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | pro_3 | task_2 |
| 3 | pro_3 | task_3 |
| 3 | pro_3 | task_4 |

Comment: You should move away from storing colon-delimited data like this, and instead properly normalize your table.  MySQL is a fairly poor tool for actually _generating_ new records.  Rather, SQL is best at querying data which already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM projects
JOIN tasks ON FIND_IN_SET(tasks.id, REPLACE(projects.task, ':', ','));
```

But I agree with [Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen)'s comment - normalize your structure, replace `projects.task` column with junction table.